# Reputation Loss On This Website

Tags: discussion

I'm confused although i have not gotten this privilege yet, it says  for losing reputation if you vote down an answer your rep goes down by one. Why?

Also I know the tag doesn't make any sense but i can't make new tags only 32 reputation

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/15863/230957

Comment: In short, voting down an answer costs you one rep and reduces the person who gave that answer's rep by two.

Answer (score 2):

By making a loss of rep part of down voting, it makes you consider whether or not you really believe that something needs to be down voted.

Down voting is not an act that should be taken lightly.  It can prevent a reasonable question from getting answered.

The penalty is relative to your experience on this site, too.  Losing 1 rep point means nothing to someone who has 4000 rep points.  But, if you have 125 rep points, it can be a significant loss.

There is a more robust answer that 3ventic linked to in the comments section above, here on [Meta.SO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15863/why-do-you-lose-reputation-for-down-voting)

Comment: (You can't downvote at 32 rep :P)

Comment: The poster had 32 rep at the time, it was merely an instructive . . . I know the privilege doesn't kick in until 125.

Comment: "It can prevent a reasonable question from getting answered." Note that rep loss for downvoting is *only* on answers. Downvoting questions is free.

Comment: I never knew that. But, down voting a question should still not be taken lightly.